# Passing User's PKI Certificate to Authenticate with External Rest Service

Tags: python, ssl, nginx

I'm using python Flask with Nginx and am running SSL and can get the user's PKI info for client authentication no problem. There are a number of REST services my application uses, and I can get and use a server cert just fine to call them.  What I'd like to do though, is to pass along the user's client cert for authenticating with the services.  Is this possible using Nginx and Flask?